# error flutter when run flutter doctor -v command

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G1Pm.jpg)

run flutter doctor -v this image run my flutter project run flutter doctor -v this image run my flutter project run flutter doctor -v this image run my flutter project run flutter doctor -v this image run my flutter project run flutter doctor -v this image run my flutter project run flutter doctor -v this image run my flutter project run flutter doctor -v this image run my flutter project

Answer (score 0):

Please review your question, it isn't entirely clear. Do you get this error when running `flutter doctor -v`? In this case, I would try reinstalling Flutter and restarting your computer. In a new Flutter project, run `flutter pub get` to *get* all your packages (you define your dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: work for me thanks